# R create shift ID where counter increases based on change in row values by group

Tags: r, datetime, grouping, counter

What I have are time stamps for different "users" and an indicator for when there is a 1+ hour gap between a user's time stamps (indicating a new "shift"). The dataset looks like this:

```
user  datetime              shift_change_ind
1     2017-08-24 22:42:52   0       
1     2017-08-24 22:53:52   0       
1     2017-08-24 22:59:37   0       
1     2017-09-01 22:34:56   1       
1     2017-09-01 22:42:22   0       
1     2017-09-01 22:48:49   0       
1     2017-09-01 22:51:53   0       
1     2017-09-02 00:27:09   1       
1     2017-10-26 22:11:35   1       
1     2017-10-26 22:12:44   0       
1     2017-10-26 22:13:10   0       
1     2017-10-26 22:22:20   0       
1     2017-10-27 03:50:05   1       
1     2017-11-10 23:47:55   1       
1     2018-03-02 09:14:40   1       
1     2018-03-02 09:36:17   0       
1     2018-03-02 09:38:33   0       
2     2017-07-10 20:30:52   0       
2     2017-07-10 20:49:48   0       
2     2017-07-10 20:52:37   0       
2     2017-07-12 17:13:11   1       
2     2017-07-12 17:19:52   0       
2     2017-07-12 19:14:21   1       
2     2017-07-12 19:17:12   0
```

Code here:

```
data = structure(list(user = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), datetime = structure(c(1503614572.35, 
1503615232.527, 1503615577.937, 1504305296.2, 1504305742.53, 
1504306129.867, 1504306313.847, 1504312029.627, 1509055895.44, 
1509055964.003, 1509055990.587, 1509056540.84, 1509076205.797, 
1510357675.767, 1519982080, 1519983377, 1519983513, 1499718652.61, 
1499719788.737, 1499719957.883, 1499879591.997, 1499879992.94, 
1499886861.447, 1499887032.547), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), shift_change_ind = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

What I need is to create a "shift ID" column, grouped by the user, that increases the ID counter anytime a 1 appears, resulting in a dataset like this:

```
user  datetime              shift_change_ind  shift_id
1     2017-08-24 22:42:52   0                 1 
1     2017-08-24 22:53:52   0                 1 
1     2017-08-24 22:59:37   0                 1 
1     2017-09-01 22:34:56   1                 2 
1     2017-09-01 22:42:22   0                 2 
1     2017-09-01 22:48:49   0                 2 
1     2017-09-01 22:51:53   0                 2 
1     2017-09-02 00:27:09   1                 3 
1     2017-10-26 22:11:35   1                 4 
1     2017-10-26 22:12:44   0                 4 
1     2017-10-26 22:13:10   0                 4 
1     2017-10-26 22:22:20   0                 4 
1     2017-10-27 03:50:05   1                 5 
1     2017-11-10 23:47:55   1                 6 
1     2018-03-02 09:14:40   1                 7 
1     2018-03-02 09:36:17   0                 7 
1     2018-03-02 09:38:33   0                 7 
2     2017-07-10 20:30:52   0                 1 
2     2017-07-10 20:49:48   0                 1 
2     2017-07-10 20:52:37   0                 1 
2     2017-07-12 17:13:11   1                 2 
2     2017-07-12 17:19:52   0                 2 
2     2017-07-12 19:14:21   1                 3 
2     2017-07-12 19:17:12   0                 3
```

Code here:

```
new_data = structure(list(user = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), datetime = structure(c(1503614572.35, 
1503615232.527, 1503615577.937, 1504305296.2, 1504305742.53, 
1504306129.867, 1504306313.847, 1504312029.627, 1509055895.44, 
1509055964.003, 1509055990.587, 1509056540.84, 1509076205.797, 
1510357675.767, 1519982080, 1519983377, 1519983513, 1499718652.61, 
1499719788.737, 1499719957.883, 1499879591.997, 1499879992.94, 
1499886861.447, 1499887032.547), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), shift_change_ind = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), shift_id = c(1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
3, 3)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

I have millions of rows so a for-loop seems like a nightmare. I have tried using the `rleid()` as a starting place for a `shift_id` column, with `ifelse()` conditions on whether a leading or lagging 1 or 0 occurs in the `shift_change_ind` column to adjust the counter in the `shift_id` column, but am running into issues when there are repeating 1's (in the `shift_change_ind` column). Plus, I know that my approach is hacky and that there's got to be a cleaner and better way of going about this. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `cumsum` after grouping by 'user'

```
library(dplyr)
out <- data %>% 
  group_by(user) %>%
  mutate(shift_id = cumsum(shift_change_ind)+1) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
as.data.frame(out)
 user            datetime shift_change_ind shift_id
1     1 2017-08-24 22:42:52                0        1
2     1 2017-08-24 22:53:52                0        1
3     1 2017-08-24 22:59:37                0        1
4     1 2017-09-01 22:34:56                1        2
5     1 2017-09-01 22:42:22                0        2
6     1 2017-09-01 22:48:49                0        2
7     1 2017-09-01 22:51:53                0        2
8     1 2017-09-02 00:27:09                1        3
9     1 2017-10-26 22:11:35                1        4
10    1 2017-10-26 22:12:44                0        4
11    1 2017-10-26 22:13:10                0        4
12    1 2017-10-26 22:22:20                0        4
13    1 2017-10-27 03:50:05                1        5
14    1 2017-11-10 23:47:55                1        6
15    1 2018-03-02 09:14:40                1        7
16    1 2018-03-02 09:36:17                0        7
17    1 2018-03-02 09:38:33                0        7
18    2 2017-07-10 20:30:52                0        1
19    2 2017-07-10 20:49:48                0        1
20    2 2017-07-10 20:52:37                0        1
21    2 2017-07-12 17:13:11                1        2
22    2 2017-07-12 17:19:52                0        2
23    2 2017-07-12 19:14:21                1        3
24    2 2017-07-12 19:17:12                0        3
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had just realized the cumsum function would work right after posting too. I knew I was overthinking it haha.